# How to start implementing android custom themes?

Tags: android, android-theme

I want to develop a custom android theme. I have googled for info on where to start,but couldn't find anything useful. Can someone please give me some pointers as to how to start??

Edit: I am trying develop a theme as the ones listed [here](http://theme.avatarrom.com/previews/Snowfall)

Comment: You can refer

http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/mobile-libraries/advanced-topics/custom-ui-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Just create folders: `values` and additionally `values-v11`, `values-v14` etc. etc. then you can create your themes. Themes are creating in files placed in `values` folders: `styles.xml`. In this files you can decribe all your attributes to your themes.

In exmaple:

```
<resources>
<style name="MainAppTheme">
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@color/background_blue</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_selector_v11</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then you can add your theme to you activity using attribute in AndroidManifest.xml:

`<activity
                android:name=".activity.YourSampleActivity"
                android:theme="@style/MainAppTheme">`